# Which annotation to use for pattern matching and string length

Tags: pattern-matching, bean-validation, string-length

I am trying to implement bean validation. The property named pin is string type and binds to a value entered by users in view. As you can see the pin should be only digits and length should be exactly 8.

```
if (pin.matches("[0-9]+") && pin.length() == 8 )
```

The property looks like this and I am trying to meet my objective via annotation.

```
    private String pin;

    // annotation syntax ?
    public String getPin() { return this.pin; }

    public void setPin(String pin) { this.pin = pin; }
```

I have seen simple bean validation done via annoation but I am having difficult time to create syntax for the aforementioned condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `@Pattern` annotation? 
something like this:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{8}", message = "Your error message.")
public String getPin() { return this.pin; }
```